# client-server code. How to bind the data connection to a specific port

Tags: sockets, unix, client

I am trying to do the following:

Let us say I start a TCPServer on machine X. Now, I want to connect to the TCPServer from machine Y, but I want to specify the ports (both sender and receiver), on which the data communication should take place. Also, the TCPServer handles multiple clients at the same time.

MachineX: ./TCPServer
MachineY: ./TCPClient -SP 5000 -DP 5000

I have written the code for a multithreaded server (using C UNIX), and it works fine. Basically, it spawns one thread per connection. But I am not sure how to include the above functionality.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Prior to calling connect(), call bind().

I'm assuming you had to do this for the server code, right?  Otherwise, how do you get your server (running on MachineX) to listen on port 5000.

In any case, here's a C example of binding to localhost port 5000.

Example:

```
int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
sockaddr_in addrRemote = {};
sockaddr_in addrLocal = {}; // zero init so that sin_addr is already INADDR_ANY;
int result;

addrLocal.sin_family = AF_INET;
addrLocal.sin_port = htons(5000);
result = bind(sock, (sockaddr*)&addrLocal, sizeof(addrLocal));
if (result < 0)
    return;

addrRemote.sin_family = AF_INET;
addrRemote.sin_port = htons(5000);
addrRemote.sin_addr = <ip of MachineX in network byte order>;

result = connect(sock, (sockaddr*)&addrRemote, sizeof(addrRemote));
if (result < 0)
    return;
```

It's assumed that TCPServer running on machine X is listening on port 5000.